# How to insert loading dialog on clicking an item of listview

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a listactivity. When i click an item of this list activity, the activity called takes time to load and hence i want to add a loading dialog box which should disappear as soon as the activity starts. But I am not able to do it. 
Also I am confused as to add the dialog in list activity or the called activity.
On adding the dialog to latter activity, I get this error:

`android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40521cd0 is not valid; is your activity running?`

This is how I insert the dialog

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        setContentView(R.layout.graphview);     
        ProgressDialog pdialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
         pdialog.setCancelable(true);
         pdialog.setMessage("Loading ....");
         pdialog.show();
```

Please tell me what is going wrong.

Here is my complete code:

```
 public class List12 extends ListActivity {

     private List<String> item = null;
     private List<String> path = null;
     private String root;
     private TextView myPath;
     private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
     public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras(); 
        final String path=(String) b.get("key"); 
        setContentView(R.layout.list13);
        myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);


            root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+path+"/raw/";        

            File f = new File(root);
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            if(files==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No stored records for the patient", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                List12.this.finish();
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            else
            getDir(root, path);

    }

    private void getDir(String dirPath, String id)
    {
     myPath.setText("Stored data for "+id);
     item = new ArrayList<String>();
     path = new ArrayList<String>();
     File f = new File(dirPath);
     File[] files = f.listFiles();

     if(!dirPath.equals(root))
     {
      item.add(root);
      path.add(root);
      item.add("../");
      path.add(f.getParent()); 
     }

     for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
     {
      File file = files[i];

      if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
       path.add(file.getPath());
          if(file.isDirectory()){
           item.add(file.getName() + "/");
          }else{
           item.add(file.getName());
          }
      } 
     }

     ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
       new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
     setListAdapter(fileList); 
    }@Override
     protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      File file = new File(path.get(position)); 
      Bundle b=new Bundle();    
      String array = file.getAbsolutePath();
      b.putString("key",array); 
      b.putBoolean("flag", false);
      Intent in = new Intent(getParent(), Display.class);
      TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
      in.putExtras(b);  
      parentActivity.startChildActivity("Dsiplay", in);
      ProgressDialog pdialog=new ProgressDialog(List12.this);
      pdialog.setCancelable(true);  
    pdialog.setMessage("Loading ...."); 
      pdialog.show();
     }}
```

Comment: WHat do you mean by " the activity called takes time to load"? If it does, than something is wrong with your activity. What happens there? If something time-consuming, consider moving it to another thread (with AsyncTask or a Loader or whatever) and put a progress bar there

Comment: The activity reads data from a file and plots them. It is time consuming process.

Comment: @ Michal, can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: I can point you in the right direction. Search for "android seperate thread" or "asynctask" or "android loaders". Read this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html. I know it's complicated, but don't leave it like this. You'll get ANR sooner or later. Also have a look at Alex Lockwood's blog, he wrote some great tutorial on using 'Loaders': http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will go through these links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use AsyncTask as an subclass

```
class yourFileOperationTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute(String result) {
 //create and show your progress dialog here
    }
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {  
 // Do the stuff here(your file operation)
  }  
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
 //dismiss the dialog and  start the intent.
    }
}
```

then do this in your onclick :

```
//note that you can change the parameter types of your AsyncTask
new yourFileOperationTask().execucte(stringArrayParameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your progress dialog box inside the click listener
Eg:

```
public class MyList extends ListActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Button btn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ProgressDialog pdialog=new ProgressDialog(MyList.this);
             pdialog.setCancelable(true);
             pdialog.setMessage("Loading ....");
             pdialog.show();
        //Rest of the code
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: I did and got the similar error. If it helps, this is my where I added it:

       ' @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {  
  
  Intent in = new Intent(getParent(), Display.class);
  TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
  parentActivity.startChildActivity("Dsiplay", in);
  ProgressDialog pdialog=new ProgressDialog(List12.this);
  pdialog.setCancelable(true);
  pdialog.setMessage("Loading ....");
  pdialog.show();
  
 }'

Comment: On the line `Intent in = new Intent(getParent(), Display.class);` use `Intent in = new Intent(List12.this.getParent(), Display.class); ` See if this works ??

Comment: No, gives the same error. And the problem is that because I use this dialog after starting my activity, the dialog doesnt prove to be useful here.

Comment: Seems soo... Did you try placing the dialog first then calling the activity

Comment: But the dialog is giving the above error :( So i dont know if it works.

Comment: provide the complete code and the log cat for the error please

Comment: I dont know how to avoid this error `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40524f88 is not valid; is your activity running?`

Comment: This is coming because your trying to add a new windows in this case the dialog box, show the code for the dialog box